# Which backend service to use for iOS client, flask vs node.js vs firebase firestore?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is not a coding query. Rather an starting point query.

I am new to iOS app development. I have been given a project by my university to make two iOS applications. One application will store few information about dustbin, like the dustbin's serial number, its type and its location in the campus. The location are named as zone A or B or C. These locations will contain their respective geographic information. These information will be sent to another iOS app. The second iOS app have the functionality of generating a map and routing the app user to the dustbin location. The map and routing facility is to be provided by HERE APIs (it is a constraint, and I cant be flexible with this). All this information flow will be facilitated by a server in between. Also, there should be a database storage management system.

Now note that, the server is not generating any active information itself. It is acting as a PASSIVE element. Client_1 is sending the message to Client_2, and this message is going through the server. this message is of course stored in a database.

Now I have few questions, or I should say few points that I dont understand and I am stuck at it.

- Should I use Flask or node.js or Firebase firestore is sufficient?
- If I do need to use firestore with flask or node.js, where shall I implement the firestore    framework, on the server side (flask or node.js) or at the client side (iOS) ?
- If I have to use the firestore in client side, do I need to implement it on both the client codes?
- Given that I have to use firestore with one of the server, which one shall I use? Flask or node.js?

The above are few queries, which will help me get started on iOS app development. (Note that the iOS coding is being done with Swift 5.1)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore will work only as your database, where you could keep collections and documents, regarding the dustbins. As mentioned in the official [Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore):

> Use our flexible, scalable NoSQL cloud database to store and sync data for client- and server-side development.

So, you can actually develop your applications using it on either client or server sides. It would depend more on what you would prefer. Firestore supports Node.js, so, considering that, using Node.js makes more sense than Flask. 
You can get a nice tutorial on how to do that, accessing the below article.

- [Write to cloud Firestore using node.js server](https://medium.com/feedflood/write-to-cloud-firestore-using-node-js-server-c84859fefb86)

However, it's possible to use Firestore, as very well explained in [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-cloud-firestore-for-ios--cms-30910), directly with Swift.

There isn't a "final" or correct answer for your question. For this reason, I would recommend you to take a look at both of them and make the decision based on your knowledge and preferences.

Let me know if the information helped you!